# alert message shows when the user clicks the image without clickable area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

I am using a simple image map as per the w3 tutorial,

```
<p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets to watch it closer:</p>

<img src="hj.png"  alt="skitch" usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,110,210,150" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">

</map>
```

I need to alert the user, if he clicks the image's non click able area. I have searched a lot for this and found lot of tutorial, but couldn't find the exact. Is there any way to do it in java script, though I am newbie to jquery. If there is only jquery solution, please give me some tutorials with examples.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Just out of curiosity isn't the fact that nothing happens enough of a clue they clicked the wrong place? You might be over thinking this.

Comment: i am working on a surf club's project. They provided an image with 2 flags. The user need to click between the flags. if else, they have to display an alert message regarding the saftey issue.

Comment: Fair enough, see answer. Technically you'll have to create clickable areas for the areas you don't want clicked... as unintuitive as that sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new clickable areas in the image map that cover the areas the person shouldn't click then set it like this:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="0,110,210,150" alt="Not Here" href="#" onclick="alert('Don\'t click here')">
```